# JSON Patching in Swift

Tags: json, cocoa, swift

I have a web socket that is pushing me JSON every second. The first response from the server is a full dictionary:

```
{
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : {
        "key4" : "value3"
    },
    "key3" : "value2"
}
```

Every second the server pushes me a new JSON dictionary, but only including the values that should be changed:

```
{
    "key1" : "olderButStillNew",
    "key2" : {
        "key4" : "newValue"
    }
}
```

I want this to result in the following dictionary:

```
{
    "key1" : "olderButStillNew",
    "key2" : {
        "key4" : "newValue"
    },
    "key3" : "value2"
}
```

I'm currently using SwiftyJSON to parse and handle the JSON. Is there a good way I should be accomplishing this "patch"?

Any ideas or help would be great!

Comment: You need to change your server to send all the values instead of the values that changed

Comment: I sadly don't have control over that, otherwise I already would've.

Comment: You can receive the json message and add the missing fields before use it.  To do this you should need to centralize your messages in one place and distribute the messages to your application.

Comment: Just get the response and add/update your dictionary values

Answer (score 0):

if you're expecting an explicit value type eg `String` you could do something like

```
if let value = responseJson["key"].String {
   //update the value
}
```

Then you will have to do this for all your possible key